# Incremental Development - Agile or Plan Driven

Tags: agile

I'm currently confused in incremental software methodology
what is the main difference between incremental development which adopt plan driven approach and the one that adopt agile approach ?

can anyone explain to me what is the difference between those two and if my choice was good for the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learning is at the core of the agile approaches. It embraces the fact that it is almost impossible to have enough information to make detailed plan up front. Instead implementing, or possibly trying to implement, your first feature will trigger very valuable learnings. Both about your implementation and the usage and actual needs in the field.

I'm not sure what "documentations are really important" actually means, but dividing implementation along module boundaries will cause a number of unwanted effects:

- you can only learn about the usage of the complete system after all modules are done, a.k.a. Too late. That will drive unknown remaining amount of work after you thought you were done.
- how do you know that the first module is done? Presumably based on some guesswork about what it should do, which might be right but most probably is at least slightly wrong, which causes unknown late modifications
- integration problems will also show up after the third module was supposed to be finished

All three drive late realizations about problems and unknown amount of work left to the end.

Agile focuses on driving out these learnings and information by forcing early feedback, such as early integration (as soon as there is a skeleton for the three modules), user feedback by forcing implementation of one user level feature at a time with demos of them as soon as hty are ready.

It is a strategy for minimizing risks in all software endeavours.

In my mind, you should have gone for an agile aproach.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your answer sir. Can you please explain to me the difference between incremental in agile and in plan driven how do they differ? i have read that incremental is concerned with dividing the system into multiple modules and then apply the development cycle to each module after that integrate them together. But with agile how incremental is achieved ? is it by only adding new functionality to the system or by something else

Comment: Yes, the incrementallity in agile approaches is in functionality, not modules

Comment: So, to do that list the features you want your complete system to have an start with a lightweight design idea, then start implementing the features one by one.

Comment: You could consider your list of features your plan, so in that sense it's still plan driven. But quite a different kind.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much sir.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry for bothering. I have one small request if you don't mind. Can you please edit your answer and provide a short list of the advantages and disadvantages of using incremental agile methodology ?